# what is the problem with my post batch request?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am using the batch to send updates to backend.
here is my batch call (copied from developper tool)

```
--batch_803d-f2f6-f119
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_1734-3336-d120

--changeset_1734-3336-d120
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST ZPM_PHOTO_CREATESet HTTP/1.1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
sap-contextid-accept: header
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0
x-csrf-token: vs9mX4SuO6tubA1-COum6w==
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 3761

{"Reqdefectnotificationid":"000013215480","Reqphoto":"<base64 photo string>","Reqphotoname":"test_1600778272163.jpg","Documentnumber":"1"}
--changeset_1734-3336-d120
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST ZPM_PHOTO_CREATESet HTTP/1.1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
sap-contextid-accept: header
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0
x-csrf-token: vs9mX4SuO6tubA1-COum6w==
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 3761

{"Reqdefectnotificationid":"000013215479","Reqphoto":"<base64 photo string>","Reqphotoname":"test_1600778262092.jpg","Documentnumber":"1"}
--changeset_1734-3336-d120--

--batch_803d-f2f6-f119—
```

And this is the response I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><code>/IWFND/CM_BEC/026</code><message xml:lang="en">RFC Error: The current application has triggered a termination with a short dump.</message><innererror><application><component_id>PM</component_id><service_namespace>/SAP/</service_namespace><service_id>ZPM_MOBILE_REPORTING_SRV</service_id><service_version>0001</service_version></application><transactionid>5F6A4914294E4AEEE10000000AC83065</transactionid><timestamp>20200922185333.4113780</timestamp><Error_Resolution><SAP_Transaction>Run transaction /IWFND/ERROR_LOG on SAP Gateway hub system and search for entries with the timestamp above for more details</SAP_Transaction><SAP_Note>See SAP Note 1797736 for error analysis (https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1797736)</SAP_Note><Batch_SAP_Note>See SAP Note 1869434 for details about working with $batch (https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1869434)</Batch_SAP_Note></Error_Resolution><errordetails/></innererror></error>
```

Can anyone advise what might be the problem?

Comment: Yes the problem is that you've used the [[tag:batch-file]] tag without reading or understanding what it is used for. You have posted absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with Windows, MS-DOS, or OS/2 batch scripting. This of course means that the wrong audience is viewing your question, and thus reducing the possibility of you receiving a solution or positive response. I have removed your invalid tag, please use the [edit facility](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64022713/edit), and choose a more appropriate replacement tag, if you think it may be required, thank you.

Comment: To identify the problem *"The current application has triggered a termination with a short dump."* you might have a look into ***/n/iwfnd/error_log*** on your gatewaysystem aswell  a look into ***/n/iwbep/error_log***  and ***st22*** on your backendsystem